# Can i keep SQUID 3.5.12 of 2015 in server UBUNTU 18 ? if i upgrade from UBUNTU 16

Tags: server, squid

i have a Linux UBUNTU 16 to update

and possibly to upgrade and bring to UBUNTU 18.04

root@tortella1:~# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

root@tortella1:~# squid -v
Squid Cache: Version 3.5.12
Service Name: squid
Ubuntu linux

when we tried the first time SQUID 3.5 doesn't work more.

Could i ask pls, if UBUNTU 18 doesn't work with SQUID 3.5.12 ?

Maybe should i exclude SQUID package fo my upgrade in to UBUNTU 18 ?

and before i have to update other packages of the UBUNTU 16

second question: can i exclude squid packages from update of os UBUNTU 16 before, and upgrade in to UBUNTU 18 after ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Kind Regards

Max

Milan, Italy

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: You mention 16.04.4 which implies you've not applied upgrades or security fixes from before August 2018 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/08/02/ubuntu-16-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but an upgrade for installed systems occurred weeks before that date) and a fully upgraded system reports as 16.04.7 at end of *standard support*. Upgrades now require ESM making it more complex (*many of your system certificates are EOL and the fix is available only with ESM*).  Also note 16 & 16.04 are different systems; Ubuntu Core 16 **is** still supported a it has 10 years not requiring ESM.

Comment: Ubuntu has used the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 16) to specify *snap* only products since 2016.  When a Ubuntu Core 16 system upgrades to Ubuntu Core 18; only the base OS will change - no user installed packages are changed as *snap* packages are all 16 & 18 will use, and they're the same for all releases.  The *year* or 16, 18, 20 products differ in this regard to the Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 & 20.04 products (*one reason why the different format is used; 16 vs 16.04; 18 vs 18.04, also 16 had longer life than 16.04 etc*)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is “no”, as there are a number of libraries that will be updated, making the older version of Squid unsupportable long term. *However*, if you need a specific version of Squid, you may want to consider using [a Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/hipod/squid-3.5.12-1ubuntu7), as this will allow you to use modern OSes that have current security patches with legacy software that needs specific tools.

Comment: Hi Matigocould you specify pls , more, what i can not do ?  , i tried to keep hold squid , root@totella1:~# apt-mark showhold
squid     , have tried to avoid next updates to squid product, but question was squid 3.5.12 can not run in ubuntu 18 ?   no ?  thanx a lot

Comment: The first sentence in the answer is the answer: No, Squid 3.5.12 can not run on Ubuntu 18.04 (or any newer version). There are three options ahead of you: (1) Use a Docker container with 3.5.12 installed, as it will operate in isolation (2) update your software so that it doesn’t rely on Squid 3.5.12 anymore (3) purchase an extended security maintenance (ESM) package from Canonical to continue using 16.04 and receiving security updates 

Comment: thans a lot Matigo , but how i can purchase ESM ,  "" purchase an extended security maintenance (ESM) package from Canonical to continue using 16.04 and receiving security updates "   --  Can i repeat a apt update and complete my natural Ubuntu 16 ?  without porblems, i imagine ,, ? -- this time witohtout doing apt upgrade .

Comment: Pricing for Ubuntu Advantage (ESM support) [can be found here](https://ubuntu.com/pricing/infra). You can use it for free for up to three servers, and the fourth will require a subscription. Ubuntu Advantage isn't supported on AskUbuntu, though, so any questions would have to go through Canonical's people 